# Using passport-slack and slackbots modules to create an interactive button bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, slack

I need to create a bot that creates one of the new interactive buttons. I used passport-slack to connect to the API and used slackbots module to post messages. The problem I'm having is the scope permissions when using passport to create an OAuth token. The slackbots module uses the rtm.start method [here](https://api.slack.com/methods/rtm.start) but this method requires the scope permission to be 'client' instead of 'bot'. With the 'client' scope everything works but the posts show up as the user who authenticated and not as a bot. The 'bot' permission allows me to post as a bot but you can't use both permissions at the same time. I'm thinking maybe these modules are incompatible and I need to use a different one other than slackbots or there's something I'm missing here.

```
passport.use(new SlackStrategy({
        clientID: clientID,
        clientSecret: clientSecret,
        callbackURL: callbackURL,
        scope: 'client',
        passReqToCallback : true
    },
    function(req, token, refreshToken, profile, done) {
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having scope permission issues when using the accessToken provided by Passport.

What worked for me is adding the params parameter to the callback and using `params.bot.bot_access_token` instead.

Hope this helps!

```
passport.use('slack', new slackStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.SLACK_CLIENT_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.SLACK_CLIENT_SECRET,
    skipUserProfile: true,
    scope: ['bot']
}, function(accessToken, refreshToken, params, profile, done) {
    # params.bot.bot_access_token is used to authenticate rtm.start
    return done(null, {});
}));
```